# ITextPDF Exception - for HR tag, not using HR

Tags: java, itext, html-to-pdf

I am getting this error message "com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested tag body found, expected closing ag hr." - while trying to generate a PDF.

I am on tomcat 5.5 / java 1.7 / itextpdf 5.4.5 / tried with 5.5.7 - same result.

Strange thing is that this works fine on my local tomcat (i.e can't see the above error) -  exactly same versions, but not on AWS ubuntu box, where I can see this error. Run out of ideas on what could be different, hence this question.

Tried to look into iTextPDF code and it seems that, they display this message while trying to find the closing tag (as obvious from the statement) and there isnt anything tricky about it.

The interesting thing is that, I am not using a -HR- tag in the HTML. Even tried with a simple - 
`<html> this is a sample project</html>` and still got the same error. 
The only additional thing that I do after this HTML string is defined is - these line of code:

```
// Add Company Logo
            String logoLink = getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/images/tenant/" + commonUtils.TENANT_CURRENT + "/logo.png");
            java.io.File logo = new java.io.File(logoLink);
            if(logo.exists()){
                Image img = Image.getInstance(logoLink);
                img.scaleToFit(150, 150);
                //img.setAbsolutePosition(200f,0);  
                document.add(img);
            }
```

This keeps the logo dynamic in the PDF.
After this, finalize and close as

```
            XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
            worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, fis);
            logger.debug("==>> Invoice PDF generated. Uploading to Google Drive. File Name = " + fname);
            document.close();                                                                       

            if (pdfWriter != null){
                pdfWriter.close();
            }
```

Any clues what I could do to fix this issue?

Kindly help pls.

Comment: That error message can only occur if there is an opening `hr` tag. Thus, I assume that your `fis` does not contain what you think it does...

Comment: Agree, I came to the same inference after looking at iTextpdf source code. However, iam pretty sure that there isn't a hr tag in the html, proven by printing out the inputstream to log. Also, tried with a sample string as well. Still scratching my head on this.... Any other ideas? Disabled the img as that's the only additional thing added to document. As a different approach, is there a way to disable / ignore end  tag errors and continue with what it's got?

Comment: Interesting Observation :
The key difference between my production (where issue occurs) and dev environment (where issue doesnt occur) - was that in Prod, the route was - Browser > Apache > Tomcat, while in Dev it was Browser > Tomcat (no apache).

Accessed tomcat directly in Production and the results are same as dev, i.e no Error. In other words, the issue occurs because of apache httpd in the middle. 

Accessing same URL from PostMan, with and without Apache httpd server, apache seems to add few more headers, otherwise, everything else seemx same  (response body) as expected.

Comment: Disabled this header which might have caused different interpretation by iTextPdf - ```ContentEncoding = gzip``` - by executing - ```sudo a2dismod deflate```  - but no luck. 
Any idea what else could I try with apache which might be making ITextPdf produce this error?

Comment: Apache adds the following additional headers compared to directly acccessing tomcat - ```Vary=Accept-Encoding ; Content-Encoding=gzip; Keep-Alive=timeout=5, max=100; Connection=Keep-Alive```

Comment: Consider pumping the `fis` content into a byte array and logging that before wrapping the byte array in a byte array input stream and feeding it to the `worker`. At least for debugging this issue. That way you see exactly what is fed into itext.